# Find information in cell-format in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, cell

I have the following cell:

```
matr = '01/07/2012'    '00:00'    [ 0.2000]
       '05/07/2012'    '17:00'    [      1]
       '05/07/2012'    '20:00'    [ 8.4000]
       '05/07/2012'    '21:00'    [ 1.2000]
       '06/07/2012'    '02:00'    [ 0.4000]
       '06/07/2012'    '19:00'    [      5]
       '07/07/2012'    '01:00'    [      7]
       '08/07/2012'    '00:00'    [ 4.2000]
       '08/07/2012'    '01:00'    [      3]
       '08/07/2012'    '04:00'    [ 0.2000]
       '09/07/2012'    '16:00'    [ 0.2000]
       '09/07/2012'    '23:00'    [      3]
       '22/07/2012'    '20:00'    [ 4.2000]
       '23/07/2012'    '20:00'    [ 1.2000]
       '23/07/2012'    '22:00'    [ 5.4000]
       '25/07/2012'    '22:00'    [14.6000]
       '27/07/2012'    '21:00'    [ 0.2000]
       '28/07/2012'    '23:00'    [ 0.2000]
       '30/07/2012'    '20:00'    [ 0.2000]
```

I want to select only informations between 20:00 and 23:00. How do I proceed, once matr(:,2) is a string information?

Comment: You'll need to convert the time information to a number so you can use the > or < operators for the comparison, see this http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/datenum.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only concerned about the hour, then just use that column to create an index array. This can be done quickly with the datevec function.

```
[~,~,~,H] = datevec(matr(:,2));
idx = H >= 20 & H <= 23;
matr(idx,:)
```